# Laravel 5 : on success Validation Request function

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

In laravel 5, we can now use the Request classes for input validation like so :

```
    public function store(StoreItemRequest $request)
    {
        $item = Item::create($request->all());
        return 'success';
    }
```

When the validation fails, I can get the errors thanks to the `response` function in the `Request` class :

```
    public function response(array $errors) {
       return response()->json(['errors' => $errors]);
    }
```

But what if the validation succeeds? Is there a function that would get automatically triggered like so :

```
    public function ????(){
         if($request->ajax())
           return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }
```

**Note: it is required** that the content of the function `store` does NOT get executed if the request is ajax (just as it would not get executed if the validation fails).

Comment: have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I found `validate` method in `ValidateWhenResolvedTrait` which you could override in your form request class;

```
public function validate(){

     $instance = $this->getValidatorInstance();

      if($this->passesAuthorization()){
             $this->failedAuthorization();
       }elseif(!$instance->passes()){
              $this->failedValidation($instance);
      }elseif( $instance->passes()){

         if($this->ajax())
            throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['success' => true]));

      }

}
```

Comment: Yes this can work and I've already tried this function. However, return response()->json does not stop the execution of the store function. The code does go through the $instance->passes() part, but it continues running. (also, you need to replace $this->request->ajax() by $this->ajax() )

Comment: I edited your answer and fixed the response part with my solution to actually kill the execution of the code and send a response. After my edit will be peer reviewed and if you are ok with the solution, I'll accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: its okay. so your issue is now resolved? I just approved it myself. But I notice you are throwing an exception:  throw new HttpResponseException, how about `if($request->ajax()) return response()->json(['success' => true]);` didnt work?

Comment: My issue is resolved with HttpResponseException. With `return->response()`, the code does not stop execution. Is it a bad idea to throw an exception?

Comment: Okay I see; But HttpResponseException is sending wrong information to your browser, probably error 404 or 403 or so? you , I believe this will work; `if($request->ajax()) return response()->json(['success' => true]); die();`

Comment: I also tried this and it doesn't work. Try it for yourself. The function returns a response parameter but doesn't die.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such method. You can do this in your request with some "hacks" (like override `validate` method) but I do not recommend it.

Idea of `Request` was to move validation/authorization out of controller. If you move successful response to `Request` than we have the same situation as before (well, name changed).

I would suggest to let controller handle ajax too:

```
public function store(StoreItemRequest $request)
{
    $item = Item::create($request->all());
    if($request->ajax())
       return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    return 'success';
}
```

Is there a reason why you are trying to achieve this in a request?

Comment: just like the way you could override `response(array $errors)` in your Form request, overriding `validate()` method is not a hack, its Laravel way of customizing things. As long as you don't modify Laravel core classes directly you are not hacking

Comment: I called it a hack because I do not think that `validate()` was meant to be used this way. I don't believe that anything in `Request` should do what OP wants. He may have good reason but from what he presented, controller does exactly what he wants.

Comment: I think he wants a way of quickly returning a json response error or success to a json request and I believe its not a bad practice. Validations will still work as normal. I think it depends on OPs application flow.

Comment: As you said, I want to move the ajax response out of the controller (and into the request) because first, I want to use the success response function over and over again. Second, if it's an ajax request, I don't want to create the item, I just want it to validate on the back-end and tell me that it is ok.